# Cannot Delete User

Tags: users, services, process

I am trying to uninstall logstash, but `sudo apt-get remove logstash` fails because the user is being used by a process.  If I try to manually delete the `logstash` user, I cannot because even when I kill the process, a new one immediately pops up.  For example, if I check for processes using `logstash`:

```
ps -fp $(pgrep -u logstash)
```

I get

```
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
logstash 17376     1 99 10:04 ?        00:00:10 /usr/bin/java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/
```

Then I try to kill the process and delete the user:

```
sudo killall -KILL -u logstash
sudo userdel logstash
```

But now `logstash` is already being used by another process:

```
userdel: user logstash is currently used by process 17794
```

How can I delete the `logstash` user?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First simply remove entire dir /opt/logstash `sudo rm -rf /opt/logstash/` and then try to remove logstash with `sudo apt-get remove logstash`

Comment: That one finally worked. Thanks!  If you could give a little more explanation I would appreciate it, and others might benefit from it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following :

in terminal type : `w`

then see after the username an output like this : **pts/2**

now type :

```
fuser -k /dev/pts/2
```

This should kick the user, now try to delete it

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I only see my username with a `pts/1` after it, and my username again with `tty7` after it.  When I do `fuser -k /dev/pts/1` it just closes my terminal, but the logstash user is still being used.

Comment: are you logging in with same user you want to delete ?

Comment: I don't think so... I am logged in as myself `btrager` and I am trying to delete `logstash`.

Comment: reboot your pc then try again

Answer (score 0):

You could do a

```
lsof | grep logstash
```

This should show you which process the user has open, then kill the process.

Or...
`userdel -f` will force the removal of the account even if the user is still logged in.

It also forces userdel to remove the user's home directory and mail spool, even if another user uses the same home directory or if the mail spool is not owned by the specified user.

Note: This option is dangerous and may leave your system in an inconsistent state.

Comment: When I try `lsof | grep logstash`, and kill the process, I have the same problem that a new one starts immediately after I kill it.

Comment: Using `sudo userdel -f logstash` I get `userdel: user logstash is currently used by process 10960` and 
`userdel: cannot open /etc/subuid`